# Android: What happens with all the permissions groups that arent listed under android M?

Tags: java, android, permissions

This doc by google lists the permissions groups under android M:

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html

And this doc links permissions in Android with their permission group:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Now, not all the permissions that existed pre-M exist post-M, which leads to the question: what happens to these permissions after M comes out?

For example, USE_CREDENTIALS belongs to the ACCOUNT permissions group - but under M neither the permission nor the group exist. So what happens to an app that was using that permission? Does it still work fine? Do I need to ask for a different permission instead? Must I change my manifest at all for these unlisted permissions or are all the unlisted permissions supported by default post-M?

Comment: "but under M neither the permission nor the group exist" -- how have you determined this? They are both in the MNC v1 JavaDocs. **UPDATE**: Never mind, I see that `USE_CREDENTIALS` is not in MNC v2, though `ACCOUNTS` is.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I was referrring to the first doc that I gave a link to, that divides the permissions into groups under M - many of the permissions are missing from the table that they provide

Comment: That table should only show `dangerous` permissions to begin with. It seems like `USE_CREDENTIALS` may be just simply retired, see [this SO Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963261/not-all-permissions-in-account-permission-group-granted-automatically). Beyond that, as I understand it, all `dangerous` permissions will wind up in a permission group handled by the runtime permissions. "Missing" ones will either have their group added to the runtime permissions roster or will be downgraded to `normal`. The "more complete list" will, at best, be available when Android M ships for real.