# Runtime permissions for AccountManager

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, android-security

I'm trying to update my app to work with the new `API23` and it's runtime permissions.

User can create an account for my application, and for this I've been using `AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS, MANAGE_ACCOUNTS, USE_CREDENTIALS` and `GET_ACCOUNTS`.

`GET_ACCOUNTS` works fine and `checkSelfPermission()` returns `GRANTED` after requesting.

The problem is with other permissions (I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation). If I call `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` on any of this permissions, I get an `Exception`.

And their status is always `PERMISSION_DENIED`, even if I request them and `GET_ACCOUNTS` is `GRANTED`.

I've read this question: [Not all permissions in ACCOUNT permission group granted automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963261/not-all-permissions-in-account-permission-group-granted-automatically), and it says it should work with the final Android 6.0 version, but unfortunately it doesn't.

How do these permissions work now? I am using an Emulator with Android 6.0 (I don't have an actual device with the M installed), so maybe that is the problem?

Comment: are you sure emulator is having 6.0, because there was problem in emulator and they were not running in android 6.0 earlier.

Comment: "And their status is always PERMISSION_DENIED, even if I request them and GET_ACCOUNTS is GRANTED" -- that is because they do not exist anymore: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html You cannot ask for, let alone receive, a permission that does not exist. Have you tried just using `GET_ACCOUNTS` on Android 6.0?